# Can if statement be used to define shared variables in NUnit TestCases?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I have a test case that requires a separate contestId from the rest, but still uses the same parameters from a previous test.

Since contests can expire, I query to get the current contestId instead of hardcoding it.

The test is to make sure that a user can take part in multiple contests during the same time period. Once the first contest is played, I want the if statement to assign another value to contestId.

```
[TestCase("User1@abc.com", "Pass", TestName = "Contest1 Pass")]
[TestCase("User2@abc.com", "Fail", TestName = "Contest1 Fail")]
[TestCase("User3@abc.com", "Invalid", TestName = "Contest1 Invalid")]
[TestCase("User1@abc.com", "Pass", TestName = "Contest2 Pass")]
public async Task PlayContest(string email, string status)
{
    int contestId = 1;

    if(TestName == "Contest2 Pass")
    {
        contestId = 2;
    }

    //Do work here based on assigned contestId
}
```

It won't allow me to use TestName to define the contestId in the if statement. Is there a way to differentiate between the TestCase values so I can define the scenario to assign a different value for contestId?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not add an argument to the method? `public async Task PlayContest(string email, string status, int contestId)` then set the value in the TestCase: `[TestCase("User1@abc.com", "Pass", 2, TestName = "Contest2 Pass")]`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated my question to include why I haven't hardcoded any values related to the contestId.

Comment: Then I'd argue that your test is not correctly designed since it's not deterministic when it depends on some arbitrary external value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[TestCase("User1@abc.com", "Pass", "Contest1 Pass")]
[TestCase("User2@abc.com", "Fail",  "Contest1 Fail")]
[TestCase("User3@abc.com", "Invalid",  "Contest1 Invalid")]
[TestCase("User1@abc.com", "Pass",  "Contest2 Pass")]
public async Task PlayContest(string email, string status,string testName)
{
    int contestId = 1;

    if(testName == "Contest2 Pass")
    {
        contestId = 2;
    }

    //Do work here based on assigned contestId
}
```